# Router Link behavior is broken in Angular2 beta

Tags: angular, typescript1.7, angular2-directives

I'd like to highlight the currently active link

```
<a [routerLink]="['/route']" />
```

After rendering I'm getting a `<a>` tag with correct link, which works well.

But also there is additional behavior in this Directive which should add *router-link-active* class to the anchor in case the *href* is the same as current location.

The problem is that this doesn't work well.

```
get isRouteActive(): {
    return this._router.isRouteActive(this._navigationInstruction);
}
```

Inside *_router.IsRouteractive* there is current instruction field which should contain the current route components. And that component becomes compared with __navigationInstruction. Actually in case route components are equal - the link is current.

The problem is that current instruction is *null*. It becomes assigned in:

```
Router.prototype.commit = function(...)
```

This function becomes called after Directive is processed.

So this should never work well.

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing something like this:

```
<li [class.active]="somethingThatReturnsTrueOrFalse()"><a [routerLink]="['/About']" class="link">About</a></li>
```

This seems to work out well for my main menu here:
http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/angular-2-samples/#/demo/spreadsheet

Comment: thanks. but my problem is not in a [class.active] but in 'router-link-active'. In your example you're getting this class automatically in ang2.beta-0. And I'm not getting it

Comment: Hm.. Interesting. My sample is using beta-0 as well

Comment: yes, i see. that's why it's more interesting and quite strange. i debugged that. but i'm using TypeScript. and compiling from TS: https://github.com/deeptowncitizen/currency-fetcher

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but I would try moving the template with the routerLinks out to a separate html template to avoid the escaping in the string

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps your problem with the possible broken router behaviour but [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bim8OGO7oddxBaa26WzR?p=info) has a good solution to mark other elements with router changes (such as a parent li). The plunker includes a directive: LinkActiveDirective.ts (usage can be seen in Users.ts)

The directive hooks on [linkActive] and listens to router changes. When the router link is active the class becomes active on the element.

Usage is like this:

```
<li linkActive>
  <a [routerLink]="['./Home']">Home</a>
</li>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your example. as far as i can see there a lot of examples for Angular2 Beta, which work well. And the main difference is that all those examples use CDN JS Angular reference. And I'm using webpack + TS + CommonJS. Trying to reproduce the same behavior with CDN

Answer (score 0):

I have a directive that you can use. See Pull-Request https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/6407/files

Answer (score 0):

Here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6360#event-511390805 it says

> Moving angular2-polyfills.js and es6-shim.js below system.js script tag did the trick. Thanks